# Appending chars to a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to select MBAPaystring_48months if it is not NULL otherwise select the MBAPaystring_12months and append a certain number of 'X' to the left of that paystring. The number of 'X's would be calculated by taking a declared date and subtracting the number of months from that date and the InsertedDate.

I am not sure how to achieve that result here is what I have so far.

```
DECLARE @archivedate date = '5/1/2019';

WITH paystring AS(
SELECT DISTINCT Ph.LoanNumber, Ph.MBAPaystring_48months, MBAPaystring_12months, InsertedDate
FROM MARS_DW..ValuationPaymentHistory_Archive PH
INNER JOIN(
SELECT LoanNumber, MAX(InsertedDate) as [Most Recent Inserted Date]
FROM MARS_DW..ValuationPaymentHistory_Archive
GROUP BY LoanNumber
) as id on id.LoanNumber = PH.LoanNumber
)

SELECT
CASE WHEN paystring.MBAPaystring_48months IS NOT NULL THEN paystring.MBAPaystring_48months ELSE paystring.MBAPaystring_12months
END AS [the pay string of strings]
FROM paystring

SELECT MBAPaystring_12months, DATEDIFF(month, InsertedDate, @archivedate) [num]
FROM paystring
```

Comment: So what you are describing is actually termed "Prepend".  Append, by definition, means 'add to the end of the string'.

Comment: Basically, you are just about to the solution.  You will need REPEAT() which will let you create a string of n - 'X' characters with your DATEDIFF number as a parameter, and CONCAT which lets you concatenate strings together.

Comment: @gview Thank you could you provide an example as an answer? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @gview got it now, thanks

Comment: The main complication here is how you determine the number of "months" between 2 dates.  You can either calculate this yourself, by getting the number of days and then doing some arbitrary division by either 30 or 31, or stripping off the day and using PERIOD_DIFF.